# Angular-Translate Partial with several folders

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I have several folders with my json files. When I have a single folder, it works but with several folders, I do not know how to configure the "urlTemplate" with several folders.

```
  app.config(["$translateProvider", function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
      urlTemplate: '{part}-{lang}.json'
    });
  }]);
```

...

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart("main");
$translatePartialLoader.addPart("common");
```

common-en_US.json

common-fr_FR.json

main-en_US.json

main-fr_FR.json

aa/common-en_US.json

aa/common-fr_FR.json

bb/main-en_US.json

bb/main-fr_FR.json

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxaVutjqsuipezmQIrQE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution, I can put the folder name in the "addPart":

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart("main");
$translatePartialLoader.addPart("common");
$translatePartialLoader.addPart("b/main");
$translatePartialLoader.addPart("a/common");
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxaVutjqsuipezmQIrQE?p=preview)